# Fetch record countr from a list of tables in Netezza using Python

Tags: python-3.x, netezza

I have to fetch record counts from tables starting with WC_* from database "TEST_DB".

Currently I'm using below code to do that, but it's taking too long as there are billions of records in many tables. Is there any way to improve performance

```
for item in list_tables[]:    
        total_count_query="select count(*) from TEST_DB.."+item[0]+"
        cur.execute(total_count_query)
        total_record_count=cur.fetchone()[0] 
        print (item[0]," : ",total_record_count)
```

Comment: please fix your code - this does not even remotely work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a column called reltuples in System table "_V_TABLE" which gives the count of all tables provided to statistics are regularly collected. You don't have to calculate the count each each

```
total_count_query="select reltuples from "+database+".._v_table
```